# When I try to return a list made through list comprehension it returns something like <function name_of_function at 0x7f9f32b09ea0>

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make a function that counts all of the nucleotides in DNA sequence. I feed a function a string and I use several instances of list comprehension to select 'A' 'T' 'G' 'C' and return the summed values but I keep getting the location of memory instead of a list

I have tried running this code outside of a function and it works. It works in a seperate function when I try and print the list it prints but whenever I try and return it  i get an error like                                   . What is this "error" even though i wouldn't call it an error called?? I know there is probably answer I just don't have the words to describe it and all of the questions I've looked through don't work. Thank you for your help

```
def summary_nuc(lis):
    A = [ 1 if x == 'A' else 0 for x in lis]
    return A
```

Returned output

```
<function summary_nuc at 0x7fa4079c7ea0>
```

Comment: How is `summary_nuc` called?

Comment: Show the code that renders that output.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just not calling the function correctly.

Make sure you're doing

```
lis = ['A',3,'B','A']
print (summary_nuc(lis))
```

not

```
print (summary_nuc)
```

Comment: Happens to everyone :) You can hit the green check mark to accept the answer if it was helpful to you.